# Proper Javascript promise construction using finally()

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I am building out an `Express` API built with the `mssql` package.

If I don't call `sql.close()` then I get the following error:

> Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.

I'd like to keep the endpoints easy to follow and maintain and like the following pattern using a `finally` promise pattern.

```
const sql    = require("mssql")
const config = require("../config")

sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
    .execute('chain')
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response['recordsets'][0][0]['response'])
    })
    .catch(err => res.send(err))
    .finally(sql.close())
})
```

However, this generates the following error:

> {
>       "code": "ENOTOPEN",
>       "name": "ConnectionError"
>   }

The following code works, but it seems a bit clumsy to define `sql.close` multiple times in the same function.

```
sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
    .execute('chain')
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response['recordsets'][0][0]['response'])
      sql.close()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send(err)
      sql.close()
    })
})
```

**Is there a way to call `sql.close` as part of the promise chain after either a response or error is sent with `res.send`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.finally accepts function, you passing result of function

```js
sql.connect(config.properties).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
    .execute('chain')
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response['recordsets'][0][0]['response'])
    })
    .catch(err => res.send(err))
    .finally(() => sql.close()) // FIX HERE
})
```

Comment: or just `.finally(sql.close)`

Comment: @TheReason `.finally(sql.close)` Do you have reading on why this shorthand works?

Comment: @TheReason That might require binding the method, as it otherwise looses its `this` context